# how to post a field value which is available in iframe in php

Tags: php, iframe

How to post iframe value in php.

Example:
Username.php

```
    <form action='data.php' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='username' id='username'>
    <iframe src='password.php'></iframe>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Password.php

```
<input type='text' name='password' id='passwprd'>
```

I want to post password and username value to data.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
<form action='data.php' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='username' id='username'>
        <iframe id="iframe_pass" src='password.php'>

        </iframe>

        <input id="submit" type='button' value="submit">
    </form>
<p id="password_from_frame"></p>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#submit").on('click', function(){

            var pass_field = $("#iframe_pass").contents().find("#password");
            var username = $("#username");

            var data = {username : username.val(), password : pass_field.val()};
// make an ajax call to submit form
            $.ajax({
                url : "data.php",
                type : "POST",
                data : data,
                success : function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert(data);
                }, 
                error : function() {

                }
            });


        });
// you can use keyup, keydown, focusout, keypress event
    $("#iframe_pass").contents().find("#password").on('keyup', function(){

        $("#password_from_frame").html($(this).val());


    });

    </script>
```

and password.php

```
<input type='text' name='password' id='password'>
```

and on the data.php use the print_r to send back the value to the ajax request

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: someone hate you i think

Comment: I am having one more query . on change id password i want to display value in main page .

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without session or cookie but with pure javascript.Give your iframe an id.

```
<iframe id='iframePassword' src='password.php'></iframe>
```

You can grab username with this

```
   var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
```

You can access the password field inside the iframe with this.

```
var ifr = document.getElementById('iframePassword');
var password = ifr.contentWindow.document.getElementById('passwprd').value;
```

Now make an ajax call with `username` and `password`.

Comment: What is the point of putting the password section in the iframe if you are then getting the value out using JavaScript again?

Comment: @SimonH better ask to the person who posted the question. Its answer which address his problem :-)

Comment: that is an example . My app is having nearly 50 fields . Its impossible to mention all those . So I explained through an example .

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can store the username and password in PHP session variables and then you can fetch that data from session variables in data.php. As you have two values, its better to store them in an array and then assign the array to the session.

Comment: Is there any other solutions except this session ?

Comment: I know only cookies other than sessions... Sorry i don't know whether there are any other solutions for it... But as i know we cannot pass the data through URL using POST...